# Autowired annotated bean gets null in Listener class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I get null **logservice** in **after** method.

I used @Component, @ComponentScan, @Service and @Configuration, but none worked.

Here is my *Listener* class

```
@Component
public class LogOrder {

   private static LogService logService;

   @Autowired
   public void setLogService(LogService logService) {
       LogOrder.logService = logService;
   }   

   @PostUpdate
   private void after(Order order) {           
       logService.log("Logged");
   }

}
```

Here is my *Entity* class

```
@EntityListeners(LogOrder.class)
@Entity
public class Order{
}
```

Here is *LogService* interface and its implementation

```
public interface LogService {
    void send("");
}

@Service(value = "logService")
public class LogServiceImpl implements LogService {

    private final SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    @Autowired
    public LogServiceImpl(SomeOtherService someOtherService) {
        this.someOtherService = someOtherService;
    }

    public void send(String someText) {
        SomeTemplate someTemplate = someOtherService.someTemplate();
        someTemplate.convertAndSend(someText);
    }
}
```

What can I do to get *LogService* not null.

Comment: Hibernate/JPA don't use Spring. So it doesn't care about Spring annotations when creating an instance of LogOrder.

Comment: Please show us the code of LogService

Comment: @JBNizet I just edited my details and please suggest me for getting it not null. Can you please help?

Comment: Don't rely on Spring injection to get an instance of LogService, since LogOrder is not a Spring bean, since it's not created by Spring, but by Hibernate.

Comment: Thats not true. LogOrder is a component so far. And we need to see how the LogServices is configured to make further assumptions. So please provide the LogService implementation.

Comment: @arnonuem added Logservice implementation

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to autowire a static field.

```
   private static LogService logService;
```

Remove *static* from the attribute.

Comment: No he doesn't. The Autowired annotation is on the setter, which is not static.